# Solving Equations with Rational Exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

The question is 5a^3/4 + 8 = 48 
Subtracting 8 
than i did this (($$(4\sqrt{5a})^ = 40 $$   and than  you get
(5A)^3 = (40)^4 i will than get (5a)^3 = 2560000 and when i go and cube root it i will get a decimal which is not the answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your mistake is in confusing $5\cdot (a)^{\frac{3}{4}}$ and $(5a)^{\frac{3}{4}}$ it seems.

Comment: So what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}{rll} 5\cdot a^{\frac{3}{4}} + 8 &= 48&\text{subtract 8 from both sides}\\
5\cdot a^{\frac{3}{4}}&=40&\text{divide both sides by 5}\\
a^{\frac{3}{4}}&=8&\text{continue simplifying}\end{array}$

Your mistake was $(5)\cdot(a^\frac{3}{4})= 5a^\frac{3}{4} \neq (5a)^\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, given that 
$$5a^{3/4}+8=48$$
$$5a^{3/4}=48-8=40$$

$$5a^{3/4}=40$$
Now, making power $4$ on both the sides, we get 
$$(5a^{3/4})^4=(40)^4$$ 
$$(5)^4a^{3}=(40)^4$$
$$\implies a^{3}=\frac{(40)^4}{5^4}$$ $$a^3=\left(\frac{40}{5}\right)^4$$
 $$a=\left(\frac{40}{5}\right)^{4/3}=8^{4/3}=16$$